# Terraform Azure - for_each variables confusion

Tags: azure, foreach, terraform, azure-virtual-network

This is my first dive into Terraform and I would appreciate some direction on an issue please.

I'm trying to create two azure virtual network gateways in the same resource group (as they take 30mins to be provisioned each), however when I run the code it errors out in the variables file that contains the map object - either saying it can't reference other variables inside it the URI is invalid:

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.26"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet1" {
    name                = "vnet1"
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/23"]
    location            = var.region
    resource_group_name = var.rg

  dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = var.vnet1_subnets
    content {
      name = subnet.value["name"]
      address_prefix  = subnet.value["address_prefix"]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet2" {
    name                = "vnet2"
    address_space       = ["10.0.10.0/23"]
    location            = var.region
    resource_group_name = var.rg

  dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = var.vnet2_subnets
    content {
      name = subnet.value["name"]
      address_prefix  = subnet.value["address_prefix"]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vnet1_gateway_public_ip" {
  name                = "vnet1_gateway_ip"
  location            = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.rg
  allocation_method = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vnet2_gateway_public_ip" {
  name                = "vnet2_gateway_ip"
  location            = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.rg
  allocation_method = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vnet_gateway" {

  #for_each = {for gateway in var.vnet_gateways: gateway.name => name}

  for_each = var.vnet_gateways
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.rg

  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"

  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = true
  sku           = "Basic"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "vnetGatewayConfig"
    public_ip_address_id          = each.value.public_ip
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "rg" {
  type    = string
  default = "rg_name"
}

variable "region" {
  type    = string
  default = "east"
}

variable "vnet1_subnets" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    address_prefix = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name = "vnet1_main"
      address_prefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
    },
    {
      name = "GatewaySubnet"
      address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/27"
    }
  ]
}

variable "vnet2_subnets" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    address_prefix = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name = "vnet2_main"
      address_prefix = "10.0.10.0/24"
    },
    {
      name = "GatewaySubnet"
      address_prefix = "10.0.11.0/27"
    }
  ]
}

variable "vnet_gateways" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string
    public_ip = string
    subnet = string
  }))

  default = {
      vnet1_gateway = {
          name = "vnet1_gateway",
          public_ip = "azurerm_public_ip.vnet1_gateway_public_ip.id"
          subnet = "azurerm_subnet.vnet1_gatewaysubnet.id"
      },
      vnet2_gateway = {
          name = "vnet2_gateway",
          public_ip = "azurerm_public_ip.vnet2_gateway_public_ip.id",
          subnet = "azurerm_subnet.vnet2_gatewaysubnet.id"
      }
  }
}

#if I run like this terraform says its an invalid URI for public_ip and subnet (these are supposed to reference that resources the Azure resource ID)
#if the quotes are taken away it says you can't place a variable in a variable
```

I've gotten confused over this and if someone could nudge me in the correct direction of how to reference a resource id in the variable map object that I'm iterating over in the main.tf that would be appreciated. Or perhaps the approach itself is incorrect and in that case I would also welcome feedback on how to improve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
  ip_configuration {
    public_ip_address_id          = each.value.public_ip
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet
  }
```

Those two expect resource IDs. But what you are putting in are strings, e.g. `"azurerm_public_ip.vnet1_gateway_public_ip.id"`

The overall template looks convoluted to me. Instead of defining two VNet resources and two Public IPs, you should create each of those with a loop as well. Then you can dynamically reference those again in your azurerm_virtual_network_gateway resource - which you already correctly deploy using a loop.